# Javascript/ajax/node.js/other framework CORS request using jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am trying to use JQuery ajax call from fiddle to load a resource from [this page](http://pool.burstcoin.ro/pending2.json)

My code is here:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('#message').text('');
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://pool.burstcoin.ro/pending2.json",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#message').text(response.message);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

I have created the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5yq4ajn/) just to see if I can get to any sort of response but I am getting this js error response:
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**
I have read some post on this and if I am not mistaken it's not possible to do anything on the front end to add the missing headers. Is it possible to add the right headers in Node.js (or some other javascript framework) to the response?
If so, I would really appreciate an updated fiddle that demonstrates that because of my lack of knowledge to do it myself.

Comment: The server that is serving http://pool.burstcoin.ro/pending2.json needs to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: Just change your dataType to "jsonp" : http://jsfiddle.net/o5yq4ajn/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using [Yahoo's YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs41j2L1/)

```
function GetMessages()
{

$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
  {
    q:      "select * from json where url=\"http://pool.burstcoin.ro/pending2.json\"",
    format: "json"
  },
  function (data) {
    if (data.query.results) {
        alert(data.query.results["pendingPaymentList"]["_00079785104091711"]);
    } else {
      alert('bad');
    }
  }
);
}

GetMessages();
```